# Remove Activities from Stack History in Android

Tags: android, android-activity

So ..
let's Suppose the Following Sequence of Activities

A -> B -> C -> D -> E

if I do The `Action1` in E I just want remove E from stack and go Back To D.

on the Other hand, If I do The `Action2` in E, I want to remove E and D from stack and return to C

how to do that ?

the above sequence is  simple implement of messaging App, so A is The Log in Activity and B is The Profile Activity and C show the Friend Request List and  D show the Profile of selected person form C, and in C there are 2 button one for approved and the second for cancel requset, now if click any of them it take him to E where Yes or No to do the Opperation, if No it return to profile of Selected person , of yes it should return to C

Comment: i suggest you open it again instead of going back (to ensure data is updated, etc)

Comment: What you mean with that ?? I don't want to keep E,D Or E in the stack history

Comment: is it always E who can do such things? Or any of the activities can do similar stuff?

Comment: @Rajeev it's simple implement of messaging App, so A is The Log in Activity and B is The Profile Activity and C show the Friend Request List and  D show the Profile of selected person form C, and in C there are 2 button one for approved and the second for cancel requset, now if click any of them it take him to E where Yes or No to do the Opperation, if No it return to profile of Selected person , of yes it should return to C

Answer (score 0):

Well what you can do is that when you go from A->B call `finish();` to end activity A, same for B->C, that is end B. So by the time you reach E, only E will be active. So now when you do `Action1`, call Activity D, and when you do `Action2` call activity C. And this time call `finish();` on E. This would do exactly what you want.

Comment: it dose not work for me because I implement a simple sign in and profile view application

Comment: Well when you click on the "sign in" button, call finish(); on it, and view profile... what is wrong in that?

Comment: Ya you are right in first status, but I can't call finish when go from B->c coz it will destroy the profile activity for the sign in person

Comment: ok I read the added description you added in question, don't call finish(); when B->C, or any case. Call finish();  when leaving E, D and C, and from E according to Action call the required activity, with the name of the person sent as Intent.getExtra(); . Experiment with this, and you will get what you want.

Comment: @MGCR7: so did you try... tell me if you still have some problem

Answer (score 0):

If `Action1` do nothing since if a user press the Back button, `E` will be removed and you are back to `D`. If `Action2`, start `C` with flag `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP`, the `D` and `E` would be cleared from the stack

Answer (score 0):

Every time when you move from one Activity to another you can add this flag with the intent Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP. This will clear your all previous activities so that in Activity E there will be no Activity in Stack.

Answer (score 0):

If it always the last activity who is going to perform this kind of action then you can start that last activity for result. So when  D is spawning E, do it using [startActivityForResult (Intent intent, int requestCode)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#startActivityForResult%28android.content.Intent,%20int%29). And later when you perform actions in E, call `finish()` for E and before doing that pass a result code to D. Based on that result you can either do nothing (so D will remain as it is) or you can call `finish()` on D as well.

Answer (score 0):

if by stack u mean recent application then to clear recent application you can add

```
android:excludeFromRecents="true"
```

inside your activity tag in manifest.xml